# Tricky NSArray iteration

Tags: ios, nsarray, iteration

I have an NSArray(mainArray) that contains 28 items and I want to divide that array into 7 arrays containing 4 items each. Is it possible for me to grab the first 4 items from mainArray, add them to a subArray, then grab the ***NEXT*** 4 items and add them to the subArray, and so on until I iterate through all 28 items? If it is possible, how?

Here's my mainArray:

```
{item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9, item10, item11, item12, item13, item14, item15, item16, item17, item18, item19, item20, item21, item22, item23, item24, item25, item26, item27, item28}
```

I need to change it to this (groupedArray):

```
{item1, item2, item3, item4}, {item5, item6, item7, item8}, {item9, item10, item11, item12}, {item13, item14, item15, item16}, {item17, item18, item19, item20}, {item21, item22, item23, item24}, {item25, item26, item27, item28}
```

This is what I've tried:

```
int i; int j;
for (i=0, j=1; i<28; i++, j*=4 ) {
    NSArray *smallArray = [mainArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, j)];
    [groupedArray addObjectsFromArray:smallArray];
}
```

Thanks,

DB

Comment: `-subarrayWithRange:`

Comment: Have you attempted anything? Show what you have tried.

Comment: @rmaddy, I've tried to use '-subArrayWithRange', but I just can't get the iteration loop to work correctly. My "for" loop isn't correct. I don't know how to increment it properly.

Comment: As I said, update your question with what you have tried. This will make it easier for someone to help you fix it.

Comment: @rmaddy, just added what I've tried and a better explanation of what I'm looking to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your indexes are off. You want something like this:

```
NSArray *mainArray = ... // the full array
NSMutableArray *groupedArray = ... // the new array

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < mainArray.count; i += 4) {
    NSArray *smallArray = [mainArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 4)];
    [groupedArray addObjectsFromArray:smallArray];
}
```

Please note that this code will crash if the number of elements in `mainArray` isn't a multiple of 4.